# Is there a way to execute a query on a database schema instead of a table

Tags: sql, database, database-design, db2

Thanks for reading my post. In our organisation we make use of an IBM DB2 database with multiple schema's which all have their own tables, procedures, views, etc... We would like to find a quick way to query one of these schema's based on the 'changed_by' field which exists in every table of the schema.

One of our users had write access on our database. We want to have an overview of which table's exactly he has updated in the past days. It is to much work to query every table of the schema individually.

The schema name is S_ORDER_SUMM, the schema contains 182 tables.

Something like this is what we need:

```
select (ALL TABLES) from S_ORDER_SUMM
where CHANGED_BY = 'Our_User'
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you need just a list of recently changed tables? What is the date or timestamp column name, which is used to store actual time of data change made in a row?

Comment: I need a list of recently changed tables within a whole schema which contains 182 tables. The date is date(CHANGE_DATE) in ('2020-06-30','2020-07-01','2020-7-02'). It is to much work to do a select statement in all the 182 tables, so we would like to query the schema and get all the tables where 1 or more rows have been changed by 'user2' today and/or the 2 previous days.

Comment: By change you mean design changes? Or data edits? What app are you using as GUI?

Comment: No i mean the i need a list of all the tables where the user inserted or updated records on. The name of the schema is S_ORDER_SUMM and it contains 182 tables.

Comment: Table list is in the Db2 system catalog view `syscat.tables` (TYPE='T' AND TABSCHEMA='MYSCHEMA'). It's easy to generate a select statement based on this with logic like "get a constant equal to a table name where a row modified by a given user during a period of time exists" with UNION ALL logic for all these tables. You need just to execute this generated select statement afterwards to get the result needed. Try to generate it on your own first...

Comment: Thanks i will try myself and come back with the results

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
--  'UNION ALL ' ||
  'SELECT ''' || T.TABNAME || ''' FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 '
||'WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM "' || T.TABSCHEMA || '"."' || T.TABNAME || '" '
||'WHERE CHANGE_DATE > CURRENT TIMESTAMP - 2 DAY AND CHANGED_BY=''Our_User'')' 
FROM SYSCAT.TABLES T
JOIN SYSCAT.COLUMNS C ON C.TABSCHEMA=T.TABSCHEMA AND C.TABNAME=T.TABNAME
WHERE T.TABSCHEMA='S_ORDER_SUMM' AND T.TYPE='T'
AND C.COLNAME IN ('CHANGE_DATE', 'CHANGED_BY')
GROUP BY T.TABSCHEMA, T.TABNAME
HAVING COUNT(1)=2;
```

The query above returns a list of `SELECT` statements on every table of schema `S_ORDER_SUMM` containing both `CHANGE_DATE` and `CHANGED_BY` columns.
It's a series of the following statements (one line per statement in reality, I've formatted it just for demo):

```
SELECT 'MYTABLE' 
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 
WHERE EXISTS 
(
SELECT 1 
FROM "S_ORDER_SUMM"."MYTABLE" 
WHERE CHANGE_DATE > CURRENT TIMESTAMP - 2 DAY AND CHANGED_BY='Our_User'
)
```

If you save the output to some file, for example, you may run this script afterwards.
You may generate a single statement for all tables as well. But you need to uncomment the commented out line and wrap the output into a final `SELECT` statement manually.